# Attaching new relation and returning the model

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a `User` that has many `Positions`. I want to update the `User` (the model and the relation `Position`), and then return the updated result.

The input will be an array of the format

```
{
    first_name,
    last_name,
    email,
    ... (other user information),
    positions : [
        {
            id,
            name,
            descriton
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

My update function currently is

```
public function update($id)
{
    // This is a validation that works fine
    if ( ! User::isValid(Input::all())) return $this->withValidation(User::$errors);

    $user = User::with('positions')->find($id);

    $new_ids = array_pluck(Input::get('positions'), 'id'); 
    $user->positions()->sync($new_ids);

    $user->update(Input::all());

    return $user;
}
```

My `User` and its permissions are updated, but I still get the old $user's relationship back (i.e. the basic information is updated, and the new positions are updated in the DB, but the returned result is the NEW basic information with the OLD positions).

Right now to fix this, I recall the `User::with('positions')->find($id)` at the end and return that. But why isn't my code above working?

Comment: Yes, `sync` doesn't update related collection on the parent model. However you should use `$user->load('positions')` to reload the relation, it will call only 1 query, without fetching the user again.

Comment: Amazing! If I `sync` multiple relations, I can of course `load` all correct? And will `load` work on the relationship's relation, for instance `user->positions()->load('attributes')`?

Comment: It won't work on `positions()` since it is a Relation object. But it will work on `user->positions->load(..)`, because here `positions` is a Collection, which have `load` method to lazy load all the related models for each item in the collection.

Comment: Alright thanks @deczo. If you post this, I can vote it as the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, `sync` doesn't update related collection on the parent model.

However you should use `$user->load('positions')` to reload the relation, it will call only 1 query, without fetching the user again.

Also, you can call `load` on the Collection:

```
$user->positions->load('anotherRelation');
```

because here positions is a Collection, which have load method to lazy load all the related models for each item in the collection.

This would not work, since `positions()` returns relation object, not collection:

```
$user->positions()->load('anotherRelation');
```